# Saving Parent Entity using Id of Entity than using whole entity

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have been using Nhibernate for a while but was wondering if thee was a way to save my child entity using just Id of the parent item not whole parent item.

```
Class Parent 
{
int Id {get;set;}
string name {get;set;}
}

Class Child
{
int Id {get;set;}
string name {get;set;}
Parent parent {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate a Parent object. However, this doesn't mean you actually have to load a Parent record from the database. If you can use session.Load to instantiate the Parent object then, provided you have lazy loading enabled for your entities, this does nothing more than create a proxy object which holds the Id.

```
var c = new Child() {
  name = "Foo",
  parent = session.Load<Parent>(parentId)
};

session.Save(c);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. How are you getting in depth knowledge of nhibernate ?

Comment: By fighting with it in production use over about four years.